# I use cx_freeze with my flask app, but always get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE, why?

Tags: python, flask, cx-freeze

I use python 3.4 and newest flask 0.10.1, flask-bootstrap 3.3.5.6, flask-wtf 0.12, Jinja2 2.8 to make my web app.

Now I try to convert my app to .exe by using cx_freeze.

**My app works fine in python. But after freezing, browser get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.**

I write a simple test case and it has the same problem.

This problem takes me hours. May it be caused by using template? Who can help me?

This is my setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includefiles = ['templates/', 'static/']

base = None

main_executable = Executable("starter.py", base=base, copyDependentFiles=True)

setup(name="Example",
      version="0.1",
      description="Example Web Server",
      options={
      'build_exe': {
          'packages': ['jinja2',
                       'jinja2.ext',
                       'flask_wtf',
                       'flask_bootstrap',
                       'os'],
          'include_files': includefiles,
          'include_msvcr': True}},
      executables=[main_executable], requires=['flask', 'wtforms'])
```

starter.py:

```
from IndividualWebsite import app

app.run()
```

IndividualWebsite.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for, flash

from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import jinja2.ext

from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hard to guess string'
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)


class NameForm(Form):
    name = StringField('What is your name?', validators=[Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        old_name = session.get('name')
        if old_name is not None and old_name != form.name.data:
            flash('Looks like you have changed your name!')
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=session.get('name'))
```

My index.html is jinja2 template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Hello, {% if name %}{{ name }}{% else %}Stranger{% endif %}！</h1>
</div>
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

base template is using boostrap template.

**UPDATE 1:** 
freezed server only show the

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

and nothing else

**UPDATE 2:** 
if i just return a string:

```
return '<h1>Test</h1>'
```

server can response correct content. It might be caused by template.

**UPDATE 3:** 
Oh I'm afraid I made a mistake. Cause 500 error hanlder is also written by template. After I fix it, **the Real Error is 'Template Not Found: index.html'**.

But I included all templates in setup.py and they exist in the 'build/xxx/templates' directory. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I find the solution.

- I reset the template-folder of flask app to './templates' in starter.py:

  ```
  import os
  from IndividualWebsite import app

  abs_path = os.path.abspath('.')
  app.template_folder = abs_path + '/templates'

  app.run()
  ```
- I also use the flask-bootstrap. So I have to include flask-bootstrap's templates and macroses. What I've done is copy all of them in my templates folder and make my own templates depend on the copys.

Hope these can be useful for someone want to make distribution of flask app.